# Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github, terminal

Estou tentando fazer um git push, ou git pull, e volta e meia dispara esse erro:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/tiagoferezin/meuRepositorio.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

O que pode estar ocorrendo?

Já procurei em vários fóruns e nenhum surgiu com uma solução.

Existe algum tutorial ou passo-a-passo a seguir para corrigir tal erro?

Comment: Como você está tentando conectar? Via shell? qual comando você está digitando para retornar esse erro?

Comment: Via Terminal do Linux, com ambos comandos retorna esse erro, eu dou o comando `git pull` ele retorna esse erro e quando dou `git push` tb retorna @UilqueMessias

Comment: ja testou a sua conexao com a internet? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github

Comment: @NikoBellic ja testei minha conexao, esta normal, outros pc daqui da empresa roda normal, ate antes de ontem estava normal esse tb, mas apartir de ontem comecou esse problema

Comment: ver se tem algum proxy setado no teu **env**

Comment: se tiver e so dar **unset** na variavel do proxy

Comment: @NikoBellic nao tem nenhum

Comment: so o sysadmin na causa manda um print do erro ai eu so do tipo que so acredito vendo fiquei bolado agora

Comment: @NikoBellic, o pior voce nao vai acreditar, qdo faço o pull e o push pelo plugin git do eclipse faz normal

Comment: @NikoBellic corrigi, eh que no meu git config tinha configuracao duplicada, dois user.name e dois user.email

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Teve um cara que teve o mesmo problema e depois conseguiu resolver. Ele reportou no [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github) versão em inglês. Vou postar a resposta aqui numa tradução livre:

Bom, nós fizemos os seguintes passos:

1. Procuramos no Google sobre o erro
2. Chegamos aos Links do *SO*([este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496277/git-error-fatal-unable-to-connect-a-socket-invalid-argument) e [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512202/github-https-access)) que sugeriram a mesma coisa, que tenho atualizar as configurações de `proxy` do `Git`.
3. Droga, não consigo ver as informações do `proxy` do painel de controle. Os "carinhas" de TI devem ter escondido. Nem mesmo consigo alterar as configurações para não utilizar `proxy`.
4. Achei isso magnífico [tutorial](https://superuser.com/questions/346372/how-do-i-know-what-proxy-server-im-using) que mostra em qual `proxy` você está conectado.
5. Atualizei a chave `http.proxy` nas configurações do `Git` com o seguinte comando:

> git config --global http.proxy
>   http[s]://userName:password@proxyaddress:port

6. Erro - could not resolve proxy `some@proxyaddress:port`. Percebi que a minha senha tinha o símbolo *@*.
7. Codifique `@` na sua senha (caso haja algum) para `%40`, porque o `Git` separa a configuração do `proxy` por @.

> git config --global http.proxy
>   http[s]://userName:password(encoded)@proxyaddress:port

Funcionou!

Nota - Eu só quis responder essa pergunta por "almas" com eu, que buscavam por respostas aqui no *SO*:D

Espero ter ajudado \o/

P.S.: Este é o [link da pergunta/resposta original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github)

Comment: Queria saber onde acho esse proxyaddress e a porta do GitHub. Tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Você está tentando usar o git de uma conexão limitada ou com bloqueios?

Comment: Não tem bloqueio nenhum, nem é limitada

Comment: Tiago, você conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: Para encontrar o endereço do proxy pelo chrome:
`chrome://net-internals/#proxy`

Comment: Kkk já tive que configurar proxy no git do Windows e nem pensei nisso... Muito obrigado!! Ajudou muito! S2